# A word meaning someone who can speak well to influence people

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for an adjective/noun for someone who is able to speak/ makes speeches very well and uses words effectively to influence/impress people.

Comment: FWIW, Speak, not speech. Speak is a verb, speech is a noun.

Comment: What is wrong with *influential speaker*?

Comment: A semi-related term would be **charismatic**: _exercising a compelling charm that inspires devotion in others._

Answer (score 18):

I believe the word you're looking for is "*persuasive*". This is an adjective. Someone who is able to speak (not speech, "*speech*" is the noun) very well and uses words effectively to influence people could be said to be *persuasive*.

Comment: Is it synonym with `articulate`?

Comment: Articulate means that the person uses a wide vocabulary and phrases their sentences well to provide very clear and understandable meaning. Persuasive comes from "*persuade*", which means to convince someone using words or other means. When used as an adjective, it is most commonly used in the sense of being persuasive with language.

Comment: You should also be careful with "articulate," which can cause offense in the U.S. when used to describe African-Americans. This comes from a practice of describing black people in the U.S. approvingly with adjectives like "clean and articulate," with an implication that this was surprising in a person of color. American racial politics can be a linguistic minefield...

Answer (score 14):

A colloquial adjective:  [silver-tongued](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/silver-tongued). "That silver-tongued con man convinced the entire city that they needed a monorail."

Comment: You imply with your example, but I think it's worth stating explicitly: in modern usage, silver-tounged often has a negative connotation, despite originally being derived from "the tongue of the righteous" in [Proverbs 10:20](http://biblehub.com/proverbs/10-20.htm)

Answer (score 5):

An eloquent speaker, orator, rhetorician ...

Answer (score 2):

> Articulate

...describes perfectly the first part of your request but falls slightly short of 'influence' part.

Answer (score 1):

So, to state your goal another way "a public speaker who communicates well and influences hearers".

Additionally, from followup comments, you desire not to imply persuasive toward the sense of having guile - a persuasion with trickery.  (Perhaps the worst example of an articulate, influential speaker with guile being a propagandist.)

How about '**winsome** orator'? (I don't think winsome alone will do.  )

Some may oppose winsome on grounds of its popular definition of...
   "Charming, often in a childlike or naive way."
But childlike fits especially, because it implies innocence and lack of guile.

Furthermore, Among the synonyms for winsome are fair, engaging, amiable. Perhaps I am just picking the synonyms I like.

The American Heritage Dictionary defn. of winsome notes...

```
"...the Indo-European root *wen-, meaning "to desire, strive for..."
...
"... the verb win itself is from this root; its meaning is an extension of the sense
"to strive for," namely, "to strive for with success, be victorious." ..."
```

So a **winsome** orator describes one who energetically and convincingly communicates.

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, [demagogue](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20demagogue) might also apply.

Comment: or "sophist", if you want to go in that direction.

Answer (score -1):

What about orator? It seems to me that persuasion is the essence of oratory.