# An adjective for someone who speaks in a way that he can get whatever he wants by using his talking skills

Tags: adjectives

I was thinking of "Eloquent", "Fluent" or "Persuasive" but feels like it's not what I want because the word I'm looking for isn't about how many words you know, you can be eloquent but your choice of words isn't that good.

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who is eloquent and smart at the same time. Like an expert lawyer talking to a judge.

"Persuasive" is the closest word to what I want but you can't tell your team of sellers "try to be persuasive with the customers". It's like selling them fake products.

I want my team of sellers to be _____.

Something like Christoph Waltz in "DJANGO UNCHAINED" and Leonardo dicaprio in "The wolf of wall street"

Comment: A synonym of *persuasive* is **convincing**. Such a person has [the gift of the gab](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Gift+of+the+gab).

Comment: @WeatherVane I would go for this were it given as an answer. It suggests that the persuasion is based on underlying truths rather than on distortions of the truth. The question is much clearer than in its original form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A word meaning someone who can speak well to influence people](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141360/a-word-meaning-someone-who-can-speak-well-to-influence-people)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth not really as the answer there is persuasive and it's not what I'm looking for. I'd go with "sell sawdust to a lumber mill"

Comment: 'Sell sawdust to a lumber mill.' Your only tag requirement is _adjective_. // 'Silver-tongued' is another answer there. As it stands, this question is infelicitous ('persuasive' certainly fits, and one doesn't need to have a large vocabulary or precise grammar to be persuasive) and an obvious duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A successful salesman would need to be

> **convincing**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> Capable of causing someone to believe that something is true or real.

<sup>From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/convincing).</sup>

Such a person has the **gift of the gab**

> The ability to speak to others in a self-assured, persuasive manner.
> *His gift of the gab made him a wonderful salesman.*

<sup>From [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Gift+of+the+gab)</sup>

and would be able to **sell sawdust to a lumber mill**:

> Someone is an extremely smooth, charming, or persuasive salesperson, such that they could sell something to those who have no need or use for it.

<sup>Again from [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/(someone)+could+sell+sawdust+to+a+lumber+mill).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the word you're looking for: **glib**

> marked by ease and fluency in speaking or writing often to the point of being insincere or deceitful

*a glib politician*

[Merriam-Webster]

Another good choice would be **suave**

> (esp. of men) having a pleasant and charming manner that may not be sincere:

*He’s a suave Texas-bred lawyer.*

[Cambridge]